# Custom blog module for divi outputting html as plain text

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php
if ( 'on' === $show_author || 'on' === $show_date || 'on' === $show_categories || 'on' === $show_comments ) {
    printf( '<p class="post-meta">%1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s %5$s %6$s %7$s</p>',
        (
            'on' === $show_author
                ? et_get_safe_localization( sprintf( __( 'by %s', 'et_builder' ), '<span class="author vcard">' .  et_pb_get_the_author_posts_link() . '</span>' ) )
                : ''
        ),
        (
            ( 'on' === $show_author && 'on' === $show_date )
                ? '  '
                : ''
        ),
        (
            'on' === $show_date
                ? et_get_safe_localization( sprintf( __( '%s', 'et_builder' ), '<span class="published">' . esc_html( get_the_date( $meta_date ) ) . '</span>' ) )
                : ''
        ),
        (
            (( 'on' === $show_author || 'on' === $show_date ) && 'on' === $show_categories)
                ? '  '
                : ''
        ),
        (
            'on' === $show_categories
                ? get_the_category_list(', ')
                : ''
        ),
        (
            (( 'on' === $show_author || 'on' === $show_date || 'on' === $show_categories ) && 'on' === $show_comments)
                ? '  '
                : ''
        ),
        (
            'on' === $show_comments
                ? sprintf( esc_html( _nx( '1 Comment', '<span class="comments">%s Comments</span>', get_comments_number(), 'number of comments', 'et_builder' ) ), number_format_i18n( get_comments_number() ) )
                : ''
        )
    );
}

echo '<div class="post-content">';

$post_content = get_the_content();

// do not display the content if it contains Blog, Post Slider, Fullwidth Post Slider, or Portfolio modules to avoid infinite loops
if ( ! has_shortcode( $post_content, 'et_pb_blog' ) && ! has_shortcode( $post_content, 'et_pb_portfolio' ) && ! has_shortcode( $post_content, 'et_pb_post_slider' ) && ! has_shortcode( $post_content, 'et_pb_fullwidth_post_slider' ) ) {
    if ( 'on' === $show_content ) {
        global $more;

        // page builder doesn't support more tag, so display the_content() in case of post made with page builder
        if ( et_pb_is_pagebuilder_used( get_the_ID() ) ) {
            $more = 1;
            the_content();
        } else {
            $more = null;
            the_content( esc_html__( 'read more...', 'et_builder' ) );
        }
    } else {
        if ( has_excerpt() ) {
            the_excerpt();
        } else {
            echo wpautop( truncate_post( 270, false ) );
        }
    }
} else if ( has_excerpt() ) {
    the_excerpt();
}

if ( 'on' !== $show_content ) {
    $more = 'on' == $show_more ? sprintf( ' <a href="%1$s" class="more-link" >%2$s</a>' , esc_url( get_permalink() ), esc_html__( 'read more', 'et_builder' ) )  : '';
    echo $more;
}

echo '</div>';
?>
```

I'm creating a custom divi module to add some functionality to the blog post module that couldn't be done with html/css.

```
'on' === $show_comments
    ? sprintf( esc_html( _nx( '1 Comment', '<span class="comments">%s Comments</span>', get_comments_number(), 'number of comments', 'et_builder' ) ), number_format_i18n( get_comments_number() ) )
    : ''
```

This line here outputs  `<span class="comments">%s Comments</span>` as raw text, which I need it to wrap in a class. How would I format this to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Hi i don't know if it is too late or you've manage to fix the problem. but for others who are facing the same issue just use full  tag instead of  for me it was in wp-content/themes/Divi 3 2/includes/builder/main-modules.php line 12284.